# Output don't recognize alphabets

Tags: java, random, io

Okay so this my code where i try to print characters [image: My code]

however I do not understand why my output don't recognize the alphabetical char while printing in output. NOTE: I given input of length as 4 here.
[image]

Comment: Please put your code in your question as text, not an image.

Comment: You are not completely filling your `char[]`. Seems like you are only initializing the values at index 0 and 1, however the value at index 2 still seems to be the default value for `char`, which is the null character, `'\u0000'`. Looking through your code and the loop variables, this seems to be the issue.

Comment: I'm curious: What human language is it that translates "letter" as "alphabet"? I see a lot of questions on here that make the same mistake. `a` is a *letter*, `b` is a *letter*. An *alphabet* is "a set of *letters* or *symbols* in a fixed order, used to represent the basic sounds of a language", e.g. the English *alphabet* consists of the set of *letters* from A to Z. --- Similarly, `0` is a *digit*, `1` is a *digit*. A *number* is a numeric value represented by 1 or more *digits*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix the calculation of `alphabet`. For given input `length` as 4 the calculated value for `number` and `alphabet` is 2 and your second `for-loop` is created as `for(int i = 2; i < 2; i++)`. The loop body will not be executed.

Comment: Help a bit more adding `for (int i = number; i < number + alphabet; i++) {`. Also a `System.out.println();` is missing at the end.